# WSO2 application server 5.0.1: How to run app as root context?

Tags: web-applications, wso2, war, wso2-as

When I deploy a webapp war to WSO2 application server, it gets deployed to a context path such as /MyApp How do I deploy it to the root context so that MyApp runs at / ?

I have tried setting WebContextRoot in carbon.xml to /MyApp/ but doing that just results in a 404 error. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

As I understand you want to run some your webapp as the root webapp? If so you have to follow the below steps

1. Change WebContextRoot top something like /console in the carbon.xml
2. file Rename your webapp as ROOT.war

Then you will be able to deploy your webapp as the root webapp.

Comment: Tried it, but I get an exception below:
  
org.wso2.carbon.CarbonException: Error while deploying webapp: StandardContext[ROOT].File[/home/ubuntu/WSO2/wso2as-5.0.1/repository/deployment/server/webapps/ROOT]
...
  
Caused by: org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.CarbonTomcatException: Webapp failed to deploy
...
  
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: addChild:  Child name '/' is not unique

Comment: did you change the webcontextroot in carboon.xml?

Comment: Yes I did change it to /console as suggested

Comment: Ok. I got it to work in ROOT context by removing all other web apps from webapps folder. But now I get a bunch of errors in log file like TID: [0] [AS] [2016-03-18 10:37:58,286] ERROR {org.wso2.carbon.url.mapper.internal.HotUpdateManager} -  error while getting webapp for host {org.wso2.carbon.url.mapper.internal.HotUpdateManager}
org.wso2.carbon.url.mapper.internal.exception.UrlMapperException: Failed to retrieve the servicename from the host app1.youtility.in
for every request. contd...

Comment: I do not want to use the URL mapping feature here. I tried setting repository/conf/etc/url-mapping-config.xml:  <mappings>0</mappings> but it still throws the above errors. so how do I get rid of these url mapping errors?